# Table width occupies 100% of page, and I need table on the same row with other elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, formatting, html-table

I can't get over what appears to be a simple CSS formatting problem in Chrome: I want to put a table towards the right, and a label and some buttons toward the left, inside the same paragraph. This works easy enough in other browsers (Firefox, IE7 & 8), but in Chrome the table stretches over the entire page, under the label.

HTML:

```
<div class="formrow">
  <label> </label>
  <div style="display: inline; width: 208px; ">
    <table id="tbl_Index" class="grid" style="display: inline; width: 208px; table-layout: fixed;">
        <thead>
            <tr class="">
                <th style="width: 50px;"></th>
                <th style="width: 150px;" class=""></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1" class="">
                <td style="width: 50px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- etc... -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thing is, I've tried just about any trick I found to get the table limited at 200px:

- I tried assigning `table-layout: fixed`, which, in conjunction with `width`, should have limited my table to 208px;
- I tried wrapping the table in a div and setting the div inline, to limit the table this way
- I tried styling the grid with `display: inline;` and then setting `max-width: 208px;` (you might know that `max-width` only applies to inline or block, and table is neither of those.)

What's really annoying for me is that if I go in the console and try to get width for the table, it *does* tell me 208; but when I look in the compiled properties for the table, it displays 0px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the table's style: `float:right;` and you want to use `inline-block` and not `inline` this should do the trick

Comment: It does reduce the table at the proper width, but it jams everything under the grid in the left side; I tried adding a `<div style="float: none">` which iirc solves the problem, but it still didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this css above:

```
div.formrow { clear:left; }
div.formrow label { float:left; }
div.formrow tabel { width:208px; border-collapse:collapse; display:inline-block; }
```